# Samsung Gear with Tizen Studio Bluetooth Debugging

Tags: debugging, bluetooth, tizen-studio, samsung-gear

Is there a way to enable bluetooth debugging the same way that Android Studio does Bluetooth debugging for Android Wear devices?

Comment: You can debug using Wifi. You have to connect your development machine and Gear in same network using wifi. Don't need internet just need to add them in same network

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it with Bluetooth because my Wifi network restricts my watch from accessing the network.  But thank you for the input. It's probably best for me to wait for access to the network.

Comment: During debugging using Wifi you can still access internet from Gear